# Where is this Ada character literal format defined and what was changed in Ada 2005?

Tags: character-encoding, ada, gnat, ada95

I've recently stumbled upon code similar to this, which compiled in Ada 95 mode and not in Ada 2005 mode:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test is
  
   Printable_Char : constant Character := '["20"]';
   Non_printable_Char : constant Character := '["00"]';
begin
   
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Printable_Char & Non_printable_Char);
   
end Test;
```

Using FSG GNAT 9.3.0:

```
test.adb:6:48: (Ada 2005) non-graphic character not permitted in character literal
```

But compiles OK using `-gnat95` flag (Ada 95 mode).

I found some references of this format in chapter "11.6 Wide Text IO" of [GNAT RM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gnat_rm.pdf). Is this format GNAT specific?

Regarding the difference in the language version mode, I found no mention of it in the [Ada 2005 Rationale](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-7-5.html). Then, why that difference when compiling in Ada 2005 mode?

Comment: This is not legal Ada for any version of the language. I presume this is a GNAT extension.

Comment: Bracket notation is used in the GCC copy of ACATS 2.6, [c250002.aw](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/testsuite/ada/acats/tests/c2/c250002.aw) where it’s described as "the brackets scheme for representing Latin-1 character values in transportable 7 bit ASCII as proposed by Robert Dewar" (the current version of this test uses UTF-8). What I can’t find is any official description of the format in the ARM (but then, the standard doesn’t specify the source representation of programs). Nor can I find any AI which justifies the `(Ada 2005)` in the reported error message.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in [the Ada 2012 Language Reference Manual](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-1.html)

The pertinent quotation is:

> ```
>  -- The declaration of type Character is based on the standard ISO 8859-1 character set.
>
>   -- There are no character literals corresponding to the positions for control characters.
>   -- They are indicated in italics in this definition. See 3.5.2.
> ```

Comment: The same comment is in the Ada 95 Reference Manual, so that by itself does not explain why the encoding for non-printable character is accepted in Ada 95 and not in Ada 2005.

Comment: Try initializing the null character constant as "Non_printable_Char : constant Character := Ada.Characters.Latin_1.NUL;"

Comment: Yes, that is what I did, but I wanted to know the reasons behind the change.